# For $C>0$, computing Fourier transform of indicator function $\chi_{[0,C]}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

For $C>0$, we have $\chi_{[0,C]}\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$. I want to determine the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}\chi_{[0,C]}$; thus for all $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}(\mathcal{F}\chi_{[0,C]})(\phi)&=\chi_{[0,C]}(\mathcal{F}\phi)
\\
&=\int_0^C(\mathcal{F}\phi)(\xi)\,d\xi
\\
&=\int_0^C\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)e^{-ix\xi}\,dx\right)\,d\xi
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_0^C e^{-ix\xi}\,d\xi\right)\phi(x)\,dx
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{i}{x}e^{-ix\xi}\bigg|_{\xi=0}^C\right)\phi(x)\,dx
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{i}{x}e^{-iCx}-\frac{i}{x}\right)\phi(x)\,dx
\\
&=i\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\phi(x)}{x}e^{-iCx}\,dx-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx
\end{aligned}$$
If $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ then this would follow, I suppose, through integration by parts. But in this case I don't know how to continue.

**Edit:**

If I use that $\chi_{[0,C]}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then I can compute
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{F}\chi_{[0,C]}(\xi)&=\int_{0}^{C}e^{-i\xi x}\,dx
\\
&=\frac{i}{\xi}e^{-i\xi x}\bigg|_{x=0}^{C}
\\
&=\frac{i}{\xi}(e^{-iC\xi}-1).
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is in $L^1(\mathbb  R)$ you don't need to use distribution here (because in the case of a distribution $u \in \mathcal S^\prime(\mathbb R)$ that is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, the distribution $\hat u$ is given by the classical Fourier transform).

So in your case a simple computation gives its Fourier transform (something involving  cardinal sine function).

Comment: Can you check my edit please, to see if my revised computation is correct?

Comment: This is correct. Btw, by factorising by $e^{i c \xi /2}$ you can write the result using the cardinal sine function if you want too.

Comment: As in, $\frac{i}{\xi}(e^{-iC\xi}-1)=\frac{ie^{iC\xi/2}}{\xi}(e^{-iC\xi-iC\xi/2}-e^{-iC\xi/2})$? I don't see how the $\cdot/2$ helps in the exponent; if anything, we need $\cdot/C$ in the exponent.

Comment: Sorry i mean by e^{-iC\xi/2}$.

Comment: I end up with $2\frac{\sin(C\xi/2)}{\xi}(\cos(C\xi/2)+i\sin(C\xi/2))=2\frac{\sin(C\xi/2)}{\xi}e^{iC\xi}$, but it's not quite $\operatorname{sinc}$, since we would need $C\xi/2$ in the denominator instead of just $\xi$.

Comment: Hint : $\frac{C/2}{C/2} = 1$.

Comment: Come on $\frac{sin(ax)}{x} = a\frac{sin(ax)}{ax} = a\,sinc(ax)$

Comment: No, I figured it out (so I deleted the comment). It's just quite late here and so I'm tired. Thanks though.